# How to Increase the radius of circle point in scatter chart?

Tags: android

I used below code for Generate the Scatter Chart in my android application but problem is that in the graph scatter point circle's radius is very small, so it is difficult to see.
I don't know how to increase the radius of circle...
Application is create for Galaxy Tab

Please Help

```
public class page_twenty extends Activity 
{
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN , Color.CYAN};

    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.CIRCLE ,PointStyle.CIRCLE };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);

    private GraphicalView mChartView;
    LinearLayout chart;


     String[] titles = new String[] { "", "", ""};
     int length;
     List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
     List<double[]> x1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
     List<double[]> x2 = new ArrayList<double[]>();

     List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
     List<double[]> values1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
     List<double[]> values2 = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) 
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
        renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.twenty);

        chart = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);  

        int count = 4;
        length = titles.length;

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
          double[] xValues = new double[count];
          double[] yValues = new double[count];

          double[] xValues1 = new double[count];
          double[] yValues1 = new double[count];

          double[] xValues2 = new double[count];
          double[] yValues2 = new double[count];

          for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) 
          {
            //xValues[k] = k + r.nextInt() % 10;
            //yValues[k] = k * 2 + r.nextInt() % 10;

              xValues[0] = 6;
              yValues[0] = 65;
              xValues[1] = 19;
              yValues[1] = 70;
              xValues[2] = 31;
              yValues[2] = 80;
              xValues[3] = 43;
              yValues[3] = 90;

              xValues1[0] = 6;
              yValues1[0] = 60;
              xValues1[1] = 19;
              yValues1[1] = 65;
              xValues1[2] = 31;
              yValues1[2] = 60;
              xValues1[3] = 43;
              yValues1[3] = 70;

              xValues2[0] = 6;
              yValues2[0] = 62;
              xValues2[1] = 19;
              yValues2[1] = 67.5;
              xValues2[2] = 31;
              yValues2[2] = 70;
              xValues2[3] = 43;
              yValues2[3] = 85;
          }
          x.add(xValues);
          values.add(yValues);

          x1.add(xValues1);
          values1.add(yValues1);

          x2.add(xValues2);
          values2.add(yValues2);
        }    


        setChartSettings(renderer, "", "", "", 0, 50, 60, 92, Color.GRAY,Color.LTGRAY);
        renderer.setXLabels(0);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
          ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
        }

         if (mChartView != null) 
         {
              mChartView.repaint();
         }     
    }

    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
              String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
              int labelsColor) 
    {
            renderer.setChartTitle(title);
            renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
            renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
            renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
            renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
            renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
            renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
            renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
            renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
            renderer.setShowLegend(false);
            renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
          }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildRenderer(int[] colors, PointStyle[] styles) 
    {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        int length = colors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
          XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
          r.setColor(colors[i]);
          r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
          renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
      }

     protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> xValues,List<double[]> yValues,
             List<double[]> xValues1,List<double[]> yValues1, List<double[]> xValues2,List<double[]> yValues2) 
     {
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            int length = titles.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
              //XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i]);
              XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i]);
              double[] xV;
              double[] yV;
              if (i==0)
              {
                  xV = xValues.get(i);
                  yV = yValues.get(i);
              }
              else if (i == 1)
              {
                  xV = xValues1.get(i);
                  yV = yValues1.get(i);
              }
              else
              {
                  xV = xValues2.get(i);
                  yV = yValues2.get(i);
              }
              int seriesLength = xV.length;
              for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
              {
                //series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
                  series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
                  //series.add(xV1[k], yV1[k]);
                 // series.add(xV2[k], yV2[k]);               
              }
              dataset.addSeries(series);
            }
            return dataset;
     }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (mChartView == null) 
        {

            mChartView = ChartFactory.getScatterChartView(this, buildDataset(titles, x, values,x1, values1,x2, values2), renderer);
            //mChartView = ChartFactory.getRangeBarChartView(this, buildDataset(titles, x, values,x1, values1,x2, values2), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
            chart.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        } 
        else
        {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }

    private void setSeriesEnabled(boolean enabled) 
    {

    }

}
```

[image: Image display's the output of above code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worth mentioning you are using AChartEngine for drawing charts.
Just call `renderer.setPointSize()` somewhere.

Comment: First sorry...bcoz I forgot to mention that I used AChartEngine to generate graph.....I try it but there is no any option such as renderee.setPointSize()..

Comment: there is a version 0.6 of achartengine. That worked for me. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer...Its correct for version 0.6 so I select your answer as Best.